# NGINX - invalid number of arguments in "location" directive

Tags: nginx

I am creating an NGINX global config file to be added to a website vhost file.

The code I put in the file /etc/nginx/global.d/wordpresscache.conf is:

```
set $cache_uri $request_uri;

# POST requests and URLs with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }

    # Don't cache URIs containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php
                          |wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php
                          |wp-links-opml.php|wp-locations.php |sitemap(_index)?.xml
                          |[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {

        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }

    # Don't use the cache for logged-in users or recent commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+
                         |wp-postpass|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }

    # Use cached or actual file if it exists, otherwise pass request to WordPress
    location / {
        try_files /wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html
                  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # Cache static files for as long as possible
    location ~*.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg
                 |jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid
                 |midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
```

The problem is that when I reload the configuration I get this error message:

> nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "location" directive in
> /etc/nginx/global.d/wordpresscache.conf:35

However the structure of that location directive seem to be good to me. Here is where I got the code from ([Tip 7](https://www.nginx.com/blog/9-tips-for-improving-wordpress-performance-with-nginx/))

Can anyone point me out to what I am doing wrong?

Edit:
I have tried the following:

```
location ~*. (ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg
                 |jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid
                 |midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

location ~*. (ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg
                 |jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid
                 |midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

location ~* \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg
                 |jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid
                 |midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

location ~*\. (ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg
                 |jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid
                 |midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
```

But they all give me the same error :(

New Edit. I tried to remove some extensions... and it works. Now I have for testing purposes only:

```
location ~* \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
```

and it works. Does anybody know what is the maximum number of arguments in parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location ~*.(ogg
```

Missed a space right there, should be:

```
location ~*. (ogg
```

The regex in question is a bit off also, because it would match URI `/frogg` or `/blahwav`, etc.

The correct is escaping the dot with `\`:

```
location ~* \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg
                  |jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid
                  |midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
```

Same thing applies to

```
location ~ .php$ {
```

Should be:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

All in all, that linked article is not escaping much of regexes, for whatever reason.
I suspect it's due to bad formatting/content sanitizing in whatever custom CMS they use.

Example:

```
location ~* wp-config.php {
    deny all;
}
```

Would unnecessarily match `/wp-configaphp` or `/wp-configuphp`, and even `/whateveryouwantmetobewp-configaphp`, etc. There is no performance benefit in not escaping stuff in those regex, so yeah - "bad blogging" :-)

Should be:

```
location ~* /wp-config\.php$ {
    deny all;
}
```

And even better, if you know you're using a single site in webroot directory, use exact matching:

```
location = /wp-config.php {
    deny all;
}
```

You can also look at [secure NGINX WordPress configuration](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/best-practice-secure-nginx-configuration-for-wordpress) which deals with security-related part of NGINX-Wordpress configuration.

Comment: Thank you, however even adding a space gives the same error. On the same row. I added to the original question an "edit" with the description what I tried....

Comment: Just don't use line breaks for a single value. E.g use instead: `location ~* \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {`